# ohmyzsh opens folder instead of command (autocd)

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I got gulp installed via npm. When I execute `gulp` in any folder it works as expected. But when I'm in a folder which contains a folder named gulp, it changes the directory (cd) into this folder instead of executing the command.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

Well; I found out, that the issue can be fixed by moving the `export PATH= ...` line to the very end of the ~/.zshrc file.